# gdb number of elements in a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios4, gdb, nsmutablearray

how do I use gdb to tell the number of elements in an NSMutableArray

I need to use gdb. I realize that I can say NSMutableArray count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some NSMutableArray *arr in scope, you can print the count from gdb like so:

```
p(int) [arr count]
```

Is that what you were asking?